# Is there a way to delete more than 1 day's history at a time from Google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, history

Is there a way to delete more than 1 day's history at a time from Google Chrome?

I would like to flush most of this info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Options > Personal stuff > Clear browsing data

Click on the "Clear data from this period" drop-down button and choose everything.